# algorithm - equally fill different size containers based on two criterias

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to wrap my head around an algorithm. I've never coded for an algorithm before and not sure how to go about this issue. Here is the jist of it:

I can have n number of containers, each container has two sets of numbers that are important to me: the amount of memory (x) and the number of logical processors (y) each container can have different values.

Each virtual machine has an amount of memory (x) and a number of logical processors (y). I am trying to create an algorithm that will balance the load of memory (x) and a number of logical processors (y) across all hosts in the cluster equally. It will not be a true equal among all hosts but all hosts will be within 10% +/- of each host.

How would I go about this problem I would suppose mathematically.

[image: The illustration]

Comment: I want to balance the clusters to mitigate risk during a host failure by ensuring each host has approximate the same amount of usage. A host could have 20 virtual machines and the other could have 5 virtual machines, that still meets DRS. Example, if the host failed that could be 20 virtual machine outages vs 10 for example if  hosts were 'equalized' per say.

Comment: this problem is pretty non-trivial.  Do you know the list of process RAM/processor usages at the beginning of scheduling?  If you have space constraints which are vaguely tight, finding ANY admissible solution is pretty tough.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your wording. What do you mean by "it will not be a true equal among all hosts"? Are you trying to ensure that each host runs approximately `N` virtual machines, where `N` is the average number of VMs you are targeting per host?

Comment: The load at the end will be proximity of each other since the work load is broken into blocks not not exact equals. Ultimately, I am looking to figure out a method to create equal percentages of memory across all hosts regardless of their individual capacity. All hosts will be roughly equal, 40% of memory usage regardless of host. I think the problem will be a variation of the bin packing problem, see http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-bins2

Comment: Oh well I have been working on solving the wrong problem. I was optimizing for VMs per host, hah. Oh well. I'll have another go at it.

Comment: tkm, do you need to consider CPU usage, or is memory the only problem to consider?

Comment: Memory would be first followed by CPU. Memory is more important and maybe CPU taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to minimize the relative load of the hosts, so that each one has a load that deviates no more than 10% from the others. So we want to optimize the **"relative load"** between hosts by finding a **minimum value**.

To do so, you could use some sort of [Combinatorial Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) to reach an acceptable or optimal solution. A classic metaheuristic like [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or [Tabu Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search) would do the job.

Example generic steps for your problem :

- define an initial state by randomly assigning each VM to a host
- find new states by iteratively swapping VM's between hosts until:

  - some acceptable solution is found, or
  - the number of iterations is exhausted, or
  - some other condition is met(like simulated annealing's "temperature")
- develop a compare function to decide when to switch states (solutions) in each iteration

  - In your case, you should measure the relative load between all hosts and only swap states when the relative load of the new state is **lower** than the current state.

This of course assumes that you will do this algorithm with some form of logical representation and not the actual VM's. Once you found the solution simulating your real conditions, then you would apply them physically to your VM's/hosts configuration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Genetic algorithms could also be useful in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably moved on by now, but if you ever come back to this issue, this answer may be useful. If any part is confusing, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Your problem is a case of 2D variable size bin packing **without** rotation. Your dimensions are Memory and CPU, rather than length and width (hence the lack of rotation).

I would use a simple offline packing algorithm. (offline means that your VMs and hosts are all known beforehand)
The simple packing I use is:

1. sort your unassigned VMs by memory required
2. sort your set of Hosts by available memory
3. find the Host with the most available memory that the VM will fit on and assign it to that Host (be sure to check CPU capacity, too. the Host with the most available RAM may not have enough CPU resources)
4. remove the VM from the list
5. reduce the Host's available memory and CPU capacity
6. if you still have VMs, go to 2

Here is how I defined VMs and Hosts:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}: {MemoryUsage} | {ProcessorUsage}")]
class VirtualMachine
{
    public int MemoryUsage;
    public string Name;
    public int ProcessorUsage;

    public VirtualMachine(string name, int memoryUsage, int processorUsage)
    {
        MemoryUsage = memoryUsage;
        ProcessorUsage = processorUsage;
        Name = name;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}: {Memory} | {Processor}")]
class Host
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public int Memory;
    public Host Parent;
    public int Processor;

    public Host(string name, int memory, int processor, Host parent = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Memory = memory;
        Processor = processor;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public bool Fits(VirtualMachine vm) { return vm.MemoryUsage <= Memory && vm.ProcessorUsage <= Processor; }
    public Host Assign(VirtualMachine vm) { return new Host(Name + "_", Memory - vm.MemoryUsage, Processor - vm.ProcessorUsage, this); }
}
```

The Host `Fits` and `Assign` methods are important for checking if a VM can fit, and reducing the Host available memory/CPU. I create a "Host-Prime" to represent the host with reduced resources, removing the original Host and inserting Host-Prime into the Host list.
Here is the bin pack solving algorithm. If you are running against a large data set, there should be plenty of opportunities for speeding up execution, but this is good enough for small data sets.

```
class Allocator
{
    readonly List<Host> Bins;
    readonly List<VirtualMachine> Items;

    public Allocator(List<Host> bins, List<VirtualMachine> items)
    {
        Bins = bins;
        Items = items;
    }

    public Dictionary<Host, List<VirtualMachine>> Solve()
    {
        var bins = new HashSet<Host>(Bins);
        var items = Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.MemoryUsage).ToList();

        var result = new Dictionary<Host, List<VirtualMachine>>();

        while (items.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = items.First();
            items.RemoveAt(0);
            var suitableBin = bins.OrderByDescending(b => b.Memory).FirstOrDefault(b => b.Fits(item));
            if (suitableBin == null)
                return null;

            bins.Remove(suitableBin);

            var remainder = suitableBin.Assign(item);
            bins.Add(remainder);

            var rootBin = suitableBin;
            while (rootBin.Parent != null)
                rootBin = rootBin.Parent;
            if (!result.ContainsKey(rootBin))
                result[rootBin] = new List<VirtualMachine>();
            result[rootBin].Add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So you have a packing algorithm now, but you still don't have a load balancing solution. Since this algorithm will pack the VMs onto hosts without concern of balancing the memory usage, we need another level of solving. To achieve some rough memory balance, I take a brute force approach. Reduce the initial memory on each Host to represent a target usage goal. Then solve to see if your VMs fit into the reduced memory available. If no solution is found, relax the memory constraint. Repeat this until a solution is found, or none is possible (using the given algorithm). This should give a rough approximation of the optimal memory load.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //available hosts, probably loaded from a file or database
        var hosts = new List<Host> {new Host("A", 4096, 4), new Host("B", 8192, 8), new Host("C", 3072, 8), new Host("D", 3072, 8)};
        var hostLookup = hosts.ToDictionary(h => h.Name);

        //VMs required to run, probably loaded from a file or database
        var vms = new List<VirtualMachine>
                      {
                          new VirtualMachine("1", 512, 1),
                          new VirtualMachine("2", 1024, 2),
                          new VirtualMachine("3", 1536, 5),
                          new VirtualMachine("4", 1024, 8),
                          new VirtualMachine("5", 1024, 1),
                          new VirtualMachine("6", 2048, 1),
                          new VirtualMachine("7", 2048, 2)
                      };

        var solution = FindMinumumApproximateSolution(hosts, vms);
        if (solution == null)
            Console.WriteLine("No solution found.");
        else
            foreach (var hostAssigment in solution)
            {
                var host = hostLookup[hostAssigment.Key.Name];
                var vmsOnHost = hostAssigment.Value;

                var xUsage = vmsOnHost.Sum(itm => itm.MemoryUsage);
                var yUsage = vmsOnHost.Sum(itm => itm.ProcessorUsage);
                var pctUsage = (xUsage / (double)host.Memory);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} used {1} of {2} MB {5:P2} | {3} of {4} CPU", host.Name, xUsage, host.Memory, yUsage, host.Processor, pctUsage);
                Console.WriteLine("\t VMs: " + String.Join(" ", vmsOnHost.Select(vm => vm.Name)));
            }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Dictionary<Host, List<VirtualMachine>> FindMinumumApproximateSolution(List<Host> hosts, List<VirtualMachine> vms)
    {
        for (var targetLoad = 0; targetLoad <= 100; targetLoad += 1)
        {
            var solution = GetTargetLoadSolution(hosts, vms, targetLoad / 100.0);
            if (solution == null)
                continue;
            return solution;
        }
        return null;
    }

    static Dictionary<Host, List<VirtualMachine>> GetTargetLoadSolution(List<Host> hosts, List<VirtualMachine> vms, double targetMemoryLoad)
    {
        //create an alternate host list that reduces memory availability to the desired target
        var hostsAtTargetLoad = hosts.Select(h => new Host(h.Name, (int) (h.Memory * targetMemoryLoad), h.Processor)).ToList();

        var allocator = new Allocator(hostsAtTargetLoad, vms);
        return allocator.Solve();
    }
}
```